# Android service is restarting slowly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have created a service and returned "START_REDELIVERY_INTENT" in "onStartCommand()" method, as i want to run the service even after destroying the App's MainActivity.

App should restart just after destroying the App with previous non-null intent. But App is taking some time to restart. We can see the status of restarting App in device setting (Below is snapshot). This snapshot is after destroying App.....  What i do? Any Help please?

[image: Android apps is restarting slowly]

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "intent: "+intent);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "starting slowly"? How long does it take to start back up? What is your expectation?

Comment: I want to start My service Immediatly just after destroying activity. App restarting takes upto 1-2 min that is against the requirement of my app.

Comment: As per my understanding about services, There are 3 ways of returning from onStartCommand(). i can't use "START_STICK" as i want to send data with intent... So, i use START_REDELIVERY_INTENT... Is there any other way in service to run without restarting it (While app MainActivity is get killed)????? Is it a design rule of android OS that service will always be restart while Activity associated with that service is killed...????

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "destorying the app" or "destroying the app's main activity". How exactly is the app shutting down?

Comment: Also, explain please when and how your Service is stopped

Comment: "destroying the app's main activity" means "killing app by swiping it from all running apps". (Normal App killing in Android)...

Comment: Returning as START_STICKY is creating the service just after killing the app. But START_REDELIVERY_INTENT is taking some time to restart, as you can see in snapshot...

Comment: Hello doga. Did you find any solution. I'm facing exactly same issue and I'm cery desperate for help right now. Thank you !