# How to keep object alive in android after destroying the process's MainActivity by swiping it from the running Apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

In my MainActivity i have an object. I have also created a service in my App which is started by "startService()" method.
Now i pass object to this service by intent.putExtra() and service is running fine.

I want to run my service in background, so i just destroyed my App by swiping it from currently running apps. Now for working of this i need to return "START_REDELIVERY_INTENT" in android service... But it is taking so much time to restart my App after destroying main activity. I asked restarting problem in this question [Android service is restarting slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398487/android-service-is-restarting-slowly). But i dint got any solution for restarting the app instantly.

As i want to restart my App instantly just after destroying main activity, so i have started service back in onDestroy callback of the main activity, so now when app's main activity will be destroyed, then it will just stop the service and start service again. But as object is destroyed while destroying the app's main activity, passed object is giving null pointer exception in android service.

How to solve this problem? What i do to keep that object alive? Do i require bounded service?